# Snap.svg load svg files and manipulate it

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I would like to stock an loaded svg files in variable to manipulate it later with snap.svg.

I can load a file, manipulate it in the loading function, but after ?

```
var _perso = Snap.load("svg/perso1.svg", function(f) {
    var g = f.select("g");
    g.transform("r45,650,200");
    s.append(g);
});
console.log(_perso); // undefined !!!
```

I would like, for exemple, transform my loaded object later with a buttom, or hide it... But I don't know how stock it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Snap.load()`](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/svg.js#L2578) doesn't return anything, you'll have to define a global var inside the callback.

```js
var _perso=Snap.load("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg", function(f) {
    var g = f.select("g");
    g.transform("r45,650,200");
//    s.append(g);
    _perso=g;
});
setTimeout(function(){console.log(_perso)}, 1000); // defined !!!
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js">{startOpened: true,}</script>
```

Comment: Thanks it's work, i've try before but it doesn't work because i had to wait for loading finish ? what is the event to be shure loading is finish ?

Comment: your callback is only called when the loading is finished, so you might call the following of your script from this callback.

Comment: Do you know a good docs/tuto about snap.svg. I ve find a lot but all are about introduction, not so far... if you know ? Thanks again :)

Comment: No, I don't know snap.svg so well, but you can start reading [the docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/), where every methods is presented, with a link to the [source code](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/svg.js), really readable too.

Comment: I've again a problem... sorry.